# How to create a ticket with attachment in RT using REST

Tags: php, rt

Does anyone know how to create a ticket with attachment in RT (Request Tracker) using REST service with PHP script?

Comment: Is the request tracker you talk about a specific product?

Comment: @Pekka: http://bestpractical.com/rt/

Comment: @joshi ah, nice. @Mike they have some documentation here: http://requesttracker.wikia.com/wiki/REST it's very sparse though

Comment: I saw all these. Looks like there is no way to create a ticket with attachment but it is possible to comment with attachment already existant ticket. However when i try to cooment using PHP i get "RT/3.8.9 400 Bad Request # No attachment for /tmp/img2.PNG" error. I'm adding attachment like this: $post_data=array("content"=>"id: 23\n".
       "Action: Correspond\n".
       "Text: ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ\n".
       "Attachment: ".$attachmentName."\n".
       "attachment_1: /tmp/img2.PNG"

Comment: hi. can you provide some post-request body example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove "attachment_1: /tmp/img2.PNG" 
add a POST a variable using addPostFile() with name "attachment_1" that contains the raw attachment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HTTP_Request, the function is addFile() instead of addPostFile().
-It worked for me.